# If Else Statements with Java using JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, equals, joptionpane

I am new to to programming - and am learning Java. I am trying to work an if/else statement using JOptionPane. Everything works okay, except the statements. I only get the statement "Stop and get gas!" no matter what the answer entered (yes or no).

Any help would be appreciated!

```
//This program determine if I have to stop for gas on the way in to work. 

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class GasIndicator
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          String answer;
          String outputStr1;
          String outputStr2;

     answer =            
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Do you have at least an eighth tank of gas? yes or no " );



          outputStr1 = "You can drive straight to work";
          outputStr2 = "Stop and get gas!";

          if (answer == "yes")

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr1, "Gas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


          else 
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr2, "Gas", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


         System.exit(0);            


     }
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet Does a question count as a duplicate even in the case where the OP didn't realize that their problem was related in the first place?

Comment: @SouthpawHare More definitely. The core problem here has been answered in the duplicate question, so it's definitely worth giving a link to it, where a more comprehensive explanation of the problem can be found.

Comment: @christopher What I mean is, while certainly it is true that the problem lies in the usage of ==, the "duplicate" question relates to explaining why it is bad to someone who already knew it was a problem and wanted to know why, whereas this question relates to someone who didn't even know that the == vs equals problem existed to begin with and would have had no way to ask the "duplicate" question.  Doesn't this make the questions different based on intent?

Comment: @SouthpawHare I would say it is, yes. Closing as duplicate isn't necessarily a moral judgement on the post/poster -- it's just a way of saying that we've answered this question before, which we have.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (answer == "yes")
```

When comparing `String` objects, you need to use the `equals` method.

**Example**

```
if(answer.equals("yes")) {
    // Do code.
}
```

***NOTE***: As advised on the comments, it is safer to structure the `if` statement as follows:

```
if("yes".equals(answer)) {
    // Do code.
}
```

This will not through a `NullPointerException` is `answer` is equal to `null`.

**Explanation**

In Java, when using the `==` operator to compare subclasses of type `Object`, it will check if those two objects are references to *the same object*. They do not check the *value of that object*. Because you're comparing value, you need to use the `equals` method.

**How it applies to your code**

Well, let's look at it. You get a `String` type from the response of the `InputDialog`. So this is one `String`. You then attempt to compare it with `"yes"`. This is, what's called a `String literal`, so this means an object is created there two, so two *different* objects.

Remember in the case of objects, you're comparing the reference types; not the object value, so that's why it always resulted in `false`.

Comment: It might be better to use "yes".equals(answer) as JOptionPane can return null

Answer (score 3):

You must compare Strings with `.equals(...)`

```
if("yes".equals(answer))
```

Using `==` will compare references where as `.equals(...)` compares the values.

When you want to compare Objects (classes you make or that are a part of Java such as `String`), you should use `.equals(...)` (unless you intentionally want to compare references).  When you compare primitive data types (such as `int`, `double`, `char`, etc.), you should use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a common issue regarding String comparisons in Java.  Comparing Strings with '==' will not do what you are expecting - instead, use the '.equals()' in the String class:

```
if (answer.equals("yes"))
```

You should generally make sure you check for null as well, since performing .equals() on a null variable would cause a crash.  In general, you really want your conditional to look like this:

```
if (answer != null && answer.equals("yes"))
```

Comment: If you use [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (placing the constant first, so you have a non-null object reference to compare to) you can usually avoid the null check. Although it may sound a little weird, it has some advantages (see wiki link above for details).

Comment: It's true, I know about and agree with this methodology!  I just didn't want to bring it up here since it's a fairly deep topic on its own.